# PHP Manipulate associative array

Tags: php

I'm using PHP in doing our exercise which is to get the necessary details of a user and the quiz he/she took.

This is my code so far.

```
<?php

    require("dbOption/Db.class.php");

$db = new Db();

$data = array();
$quiz = array();
$easy = "";
$normal = "";
$hard = "";

//  SELECT id, course FROM quizz WHERE course = 2
$res_quizz = $db->query("SELECT id, course FROM quizz WHERE course = :course", array("course"=>2));
foreach ($res_quizz as $key => $value) {
    $quizzid = $value['id'];

    //  SELECT easy, normal, hard,  userid FROM quizzscore WHERE quizid = $quizid
    $res_quizzscore = $db->query("SELECT easy, normal, hard, userid, quizzid FROM quizzscore WHERE quizzid = :quizzid", array("quizzid"=>$quizzid));

    foreach ($res_quizzscore as $key => $value2) {
        $easy = $value2['easy'];
        $normal = $value2['normal'];
        $hard = $value2['hard'];
        $quizzid = $value2['quizzid'];
        $userid = $value2['userid'];

        $q = array(
            'Qz'.$quizzid => array(
                    'easy' =>$easy,
                    'normal' =>$normal,
                    'hard' =>$hard,
                )
        );

        $quiz['quizzes'] = $q;

        //  SELECT name FROM USER WHERE id = $userid
        $res_user = $db->query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = :id", array("id"=>$userid));
        foreach ($res_user as $key => $value3) {
            $name = $value3['name'];
        }

    }

    $data[$userid] = array();
    $data[$userid]['name'] = $name;
    $data[$userid]['quizzes'] = $quiz;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<pre/>";
}
```

The array is poorly manipulated and that's why I'm getting this result.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Smith
            [quizzes] => Array
                (
                    [quizzes] => Array
                        (
                            [Qz1] => Array
                                (
                                    [easy] => 5
                                    [normal] => 6
                                    [hard] => 7
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Smith
            [quizzes] => Array
                (
                    [quizzes] => Array
                        (
                            [Qz2] => Array
                                (
                                    [easy] => 3
                                    [normal] => 4
                                    [hard] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I want to have is this kind of result.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Smith
            [quizzes] => Array
                (
                    [quizzes] => Array
                        (
                            [Qz1] => Array
                                (
                                    [easy] => 5
                                    [normal] => 6
                                    [hard] => 7
                                )
                            [Qz2] => Array
                                (
                                   [easy] => 3
                                   [normal] => 4
                                   [hard] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: `array_unique($data)` read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I'll have a look on that. Thanks!

Comment: Try my answer first. LOL :D `$result = array_unique($data);` then `print_r($result);`

Comment: Still getting the same result :/

Comment: The order in which you are nesting your loops is inside-out relative to how you want your arrays to be structured. You currently have the quiz as the outer loop and the user as the inner loop, but your target structure has the quiz inside the user. Also note that you are using `$userid` outside of the loop where it is assigned, so only the last value will be used.

Comment: This really helped me! I'll go and change things now.

Comment: @JackA. thanks for the help! Now I got it